# how to call camel cxf endpoint in async way

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I'm calling to camel cxf endpoint like this in an async way :

```
CompletableFuture<Object> response = template.asyncSendBody(host, xmlStr);
```

the response get give me this class : CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream

I can not cast to this class as it is private inner class.
So how can I get the information I need from the response  ?

Comment: Just use Camel's type converter afterwards to get the response in the type you want

Comment: not sure I understand ..afterwards where ?